# A small question about structure of dynamic multidimensional array in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, dynamic

What exacly this repetition of [4] does in this declaration of dynamic multidimensional array?

```
int (*array)[4] = new int[10][4];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an array like this

```
T a[10];
```

then T is the type of elements of the array.

To dynamically allocate such an array you have to write

```
T *array = new T[10];
```

Let's now define `T` as a typedef name the following way

```
typedef int T[4];
```

or

```
using T = int[4];
```

So this declaration

```
T *array = new T[10];
```

is valid also and for this typedef.

Now let's substitute T for its typedef definition in the reversed way. We will get

```
int ( *array )[4] = int[10][4];
```

So the operator new allocates a two dimensional array with 10 "rows" each of which is in turn an array of 4 integer elements.

This record

```
int ( *array )[4]
```

means pointer to an array (element of the two-dimensional array) of 4 elements.

To make it more clear let's you have an array like

```
T a[N1][N2];
```

This declaration of a two-dimensional array you may  rewrite like

```
T ( a[N1] )[N2];
```

The both declarations declare the same two-dimensional array.

To get pointer to the type of  element of the array just substitute the record `( a[N1] )` for `( *p )` . For example

```
T ( a[N1] )[N2];
T ( *p ){N2] = a;
```